# Saving .xlsx files in SQL Database through Rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xlsx, axlsx

I'm creating a .xlsx file using 'axlsx_rails' gem. I'm successfully able to save the file to the browser using:

`send_data(xlsx.to_stream.read, type: "application/xlsx", filename: filename)`

However - I want to be able to save this file in the database, at the same time the user downloads it, to be able to access the file later.

I can't figure out how to do this - saving as xlsx.to_stream.read doesn't work, other variations just give me strings - I want to save it as an actual .xlsx file.

How do I do this?

Edit:

This is what I currently have:

```
class ReportsUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  def store_dir
     "reports"
  end
end
```

Then in the model:

```
class Report < ApplicationRecord

  mount_uploader :file, ReportsUploader
end
```

Then when I save the actual report:

```
send_data(report.xlsx.to_stream.read, type: "application/xlsx", filename: report.filename)
```

That causes the download of the file for the user

Then I do

```
Report.create!(file: Rails.root.join('user_information_report.xlsx'))
```

Edit: This actually works!

Comment: You can use `send_file` method to download the file and either `paperclip` or `carrierwave` to save file to database.

Comment: @KedarnagMukanahallipatna thanks! 

I'm trying `carrierwave` now but can't seem to get the actual file correct. It just seems to be strings - do I just send the `xlsx` variable to `carrierwave`? Or something like `xlsx.to_stream.read`?

Comment: You will need to actually serialize the package into a real file and store that file externally. I would not recommend you trying to store the raw string data into the database. That being said why store it at all `axlsx` is a fairly efficient `xlsx` generation gem and building the spreadsheets on the fly is most likely a better choice.

Comment: @engineersmnky I am actually saving the spreadsheet already - but I'm also required to save the same file to the database. How do I store that file externally and then grab it to save it in the DB?

Comment: Looks like you can use serialize to make a file out of the xlsx. If you wanted to, you could write this to a temporary directory then read it in to your database. I wouldn't suggest that though. Storing binary data in your DB is usually not a good choice. From the code:

    p = Axlsx::Package.new
    # ......add cool stuff to your workbook......
    p.serialize("example.xlsx")

Comment: Show what you have tried with `carrierwave` as this is most likely your best choice but the information you have provided is not really enough to go on

Comment: *"I'm also required to save the same file to the database"* -- Why? This is *possible*, but not a normal thing to do. Databases will normally only contain a pointer to the file - e.g. a URL. I think it's very likely that *this* is what you should be doing, not saving the contexts of the file itself to the database.

Comment: @TomLord you're right! I'm trying to set it up that way now

Comment: @engineersmnky so right now I have it set up like so: 

`class ReportsUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  def store_dir
    "reports"
  end
end`

Comment: @engineersmnky I'm going to edit the original post instead so it's easier to read

Comment: Got it working! Thanks a lot everyone who helped!

Answer (score 0):

Now you can use Active Storage, its very handy, comes from the core! https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html